# Using count function or create specific column for counting in sql

Tags: sql-server, count

I working on groups project. I have those tables :
[image]

I can get the number of members for each group by using count function :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Counts FROM [Groups].[GroupMembers]
WHERE GroupId=Id;
```

Or I can add another column to `Groups` table for counting and every time new member join to the group, this field will increase by one. Does it better to use count function or add another column for counting ? in other words, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your table engine. If your table engine is `MyISAM` it would be much faster because it would simply read number of rows in the table from stored value, however `Innodb` engines will need to do a full table scan.

It is not recommended to store a count inside of the table itself, so if this is something you're worried about, use the `MyISAM` engine if possible.

Storing a value in the table would needlessly require an extra `UPDATE` query on each new/lost membership.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a column to store the count's is not recommend at all.

When you want the count of each group you can use a simple `Select` query to show the count of each group.

```
SELECT G.groupid, 
       Count(userid) 
FROM   groups G 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN groupmembers GM 
                    ON G.groupid = GM.groupid 
GROUP  BY G.groupid
```

In case you want to add a new column then you will require a `Trigger` on `GroupMembers` table to update the count column in `Groups` table  when a new user is added to any group in `GroupMembers` table